# Horton's algorithm I coded does not work well

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

I tried coding Horton's algorithm to derive a minimum cycle basis for an unweighted undirected 2-connected graph.
However, the basis often cover the all edges of a graph.
I guess that the program could correctly make Horton set .
So how to fix my code to work correctly?

```
for v in G.nodes():
    T = BFS_Tree(G,v)
    for x,y in G.edges():
        path_vtox = nx.shortest_path(T,source=v,target=x)
        path_vtoy = nx.shortest_path(T,source=v,target=y)
        if set(path_vtox) & set(path_vtoy) == {v}:
            cycel = []
            for i in range(len(path_vtox)-1):
                cycle.append(path_vtox[i],path_vtox[i+1])
            for i in range(len(path_vtoy)-1):
                cycle.append(path_vtoy[i],path_vtoy[i+1])
            cycle.append((x,y))
            g = nx.Graph()
            g.add_edges_from(cycle)
            try:
                nx.find_cycle(g)
                Cycles.append(cycle)
            except:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the question.

First, a few comments on how to ask questions and regarding your code:
You should write a self contained example. This includes working code, a toy problem and the expected output. In your case I am missing a line like
`import networkx as nx` at the top. Also, you are referencing classes `BFS_Tree` and `Cycles` at lines 2 and 17, without having them defined before.
There is a typo. In line 7 it should say `cycle` instead of `cycel`.
Most importantly, I'd expect a short working example of how your graph `G` is defined and what you would expect as an output of your code.

Now, I'll try to say something about the algorithm, even though I am probably missing a few concepts.
Is the Horton set a cycle basis of shortest length?
In general I do not see a problem when the basis can cover all edges of a graph, assuming all edges are part of some cycle. Or do you mean that basis elements cover all edges of the graph but should be shorter?
I could not find a unique reference to Horton's algorithm and am assuming you are implementing it from p. 360 in [the original paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0216026). In this reference, Horton describes the algorithm as:

1) Find a minimum path P(x,y) between each pair of points x, y

2) For each vertex v and edge {x,y} in the graph, create the cycle C(v,x,y)=P(v,x)+P(v,y)+{x,y}, and calculate its length. Degenerate cases in which P(v,x) and P(v,y) have vertices other than v in common can be omitted.

3) Order the cycles by weight

4) Use the greedy algorithm to find the minimum cycle basis from this set of cycles

In your code I only see steps 1) and 2) implemented. 3) is trivial for the unweighted case, as every cycle is weighted by its length. But it seems step 4) is missing. Horton proposes a solution on page 362 of the reference.

I hope this helps.